# How to restrict third party app (Internet Download Manager) in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, security, restriction, idm

I have an api enpoint like "example.com/book/1". which is response like:

{
name: "Title",
audio_file: "example.mp3"
}

Now i want, when i display in reactjs with audio tag. Third party app detect automatically. I need to restrict.

Restrict
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZJmI.jpg)